# How can I automatically generate a "story" from photos in a folder?

Tags: gratis, linux, images, offline

I took a lot of pictures in my holiday.

Is there something similar to [Google story album](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2634386/The-story-life-Google-launches-new-online-album-automatically-sort-pictures.html), but offline, gratis and for Linux?

(If it works really well, I would also pay for it.)

It should be able to detect similar images (which would be grouped on one page of the output, whatever the output might be) and generate a map of where you shot the images.